# how to print multiple columns as a data frame - python

Tags: python

I need to print 2 specific columns as a data frame and not a series.

this question is different from
when df1 is printed it returns a series. movie title and movie year are the columns I need to print. I used the df = my_series.to_frame()
function but it still returns a series.

```
def find_movie_by_year():
    x = input("enter movie year")
    d = df[df["title_year"] == int(x)]
    df1 = d[["movie_title","title_year"]]
    print('''

    ''')
    print(df1)
```

EDIT 1:

this is the output format i need:

[image]

this is the output format i get from the code:

[image]

Comment: provide the df1 and df dataframe values also

Comment: Your code works fine and returns the dataframe. Check the type of df1 by using `print(type(df1))`

Comment: ok, I checked the type and its a data frame. but the output appearance is different from when I print the df in another cell

Comment: You can use display() instead of print() for the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use **display** function instead of simply printing it.

```
def find_movie_by_year():
x = input("enter movie year")
d = df[df["title_year"] == int(x)]
df1 = d[["movie_title","title_year"]]
print('''

''')
#print(df1)
display(df1)
```